# How to render the corresponding field-label automatically in Lightning?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, label

In Visualforce we used `<apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>` to get the html-input together with the right label (respecting transaltions, overrides, etc.)

Now in Lightnig is see a very verbose notation in the examples setting the label manually hardcoded like that:

```
<ui:inputText aura:id="client" 
    label="Client" 
    class="form-control"
    value="{!v.newExpense.Client__c}"
    placeholder="ABC Co."
/>
```

Is there a way to populate the labels dynamically like in VF?

The expression which works in Visualforce like this

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Name.Label}
```

seems not to work but brings up only empty-results in the markup of a Lightning Component. However you can save the markup containing the expression without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just have received this reply from premier+ support. **Bottom line: it's not possible for now.** No ETA and no infos about the roadmap yet.

> Hi, Thanks for your time over the call. As discussed,
>
> - I have checked with Senior support Engineers and internal teams and as per our confirmation : All text fields must specify the label
>     attribute to provide a textual label of the field.
> - Currently, these attributes are not completely exposed.
> - I have put forward your concerns regarding giving developers more leverage and exposures to develop more efficiently.
>
> They also suggested that we put this in Ideas Exchange since this
>   might be vital for other organizations in the future. Here again is
>   the link:
>
> http://ideas.salesforce.com

Comment: Just terrible that this isn't fixed yet.. The Idea is here, please all vote: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM

Comment: To anyone coming across this post, this feature still is not available in Aura components, but it _is_ possible with LWCs. For example:
`@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: 'Account' })
accountInfo;

get industryFieldLabel() {
    return this.accountInfo.data.fields['Industry'].label;
}
`
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info