# Get field label in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I need to get and use the field label in my lightning component.

In VF it is possible to do this via the:

```
{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Title.Label}
```

OR:

```
{!$ObjectType['Account'].fields['Title'].Label}
```

How can this be done in lightning component markup or controller?

Comment: It really helpfull for you. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96514/how-to-render-the-corresponding-field-label-automatically-in-lightning

Comment: That's helpful, but it was a year ago - any news regarding that capability?

Comment: Don't forget to vote here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Answer is:

**This cannot be done in lightning component as of today!!!**

please vote this idea to make this feature available sooner:

[Access sObject field labels from lightning component](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM)

Answer (score 13):

You need to call server side controller from lightning and use following code (Describe API) there:

```
Schema.SObjectField F = fieldNameMap.get(fieldAPIName); //where fieldAPIName is API name of field
Schema.DescribeFieldResult R = F.getDescribe();
String fieldLabel=R.getLabel();
return fieldLabel;
```

This is the only way as far as I know. Else, you can create new custom labels for field names labels and use them directly in lightning using "$Label.c.Custom_Label"

Comment: I just state here that this answer is not what I am asking for - I want to get the labels from the client side and not from the server side. this is still not possible

Answer (score 0):

**Using below code you can get label for any field in LWC for particular object **

```
`import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc'
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/opportunity.Name';

export default class LabelInMsg extends LightningElement {

    data;
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    oppInfo({ data, error }) {
        this.data=data;
        if (data) {  console.log('result=> ', this.data.fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName].label);}
    }
   

  
}`
```