# Is there a way to get Standard field translations in Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customer-community, translation

Is there a way to get Standard field translations in Lightning Component? I know that you can get custom label `label_name` by using (in the `.js` controller)

```
$A.getReference("$Label.c.label_name"));
```

But is there something similar for Standard fields? For field `FirstName` on `Account` object I've tried

```
$A.getReference("$Label.Account.FirstName"));
$A.getReference("$Label.c.Account.FirstName"));
$A.getReference("$Label.c.Account_FirstName"));
```

But with no luck. Is there different namespace, or is there completely different way about this?

Comment: $Label only works for labels, not describe information. The closest I know of to doing something like that today is to write up some Apex Code and get the describe information, as demonstrated in [this answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/148039).

Comment: Don't forget to vote here: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000cNLeQAM